# Maximum limitation for Choice fields

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation, column, choice-field, limitations

I'm creating the list with `choice field(Multi Selection)`. In this I'm having more than `300` options to be added in single `choice field`. So I want to know the maximum limitation of `options` for the choice field in `SharePoint 2013`

Comment: For such amount of choice options it is better to create a new custom list to save all values, and instead of using choice column create a lookup column to that list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Choice** field maximum value : **255** & size of column: **30 bytes**

**Choice (multiple selection)** field maximum value: **350** & size of column: **22 bytes**

Reference: [Software boundaries and limits for SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/cc262787.aspx)

Comment: Is this is the maximum option count?I thought it is the length of the value we gave for options?

Comment: But what does it mean - 30 bytes ? I have choice column with 10 options, each option contains 50 characters. Why I am not facing any issues with limitation?