# SharePoint column limits. Choice column

Tags: 2013, choice-field, limitations, choices

Could you please explain me about [SharePoint Column limits](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/install/software-boundaries-and-limits?redirectedfrom=MSDN#column-limits).

I read several articles about limitation of choice column. For example [here](https://sharegate.com/blog/sharepoint-column-types-ia) and [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/181178/maximum-limitation-for-choice-fields).

From MS  Article:
Choice field maximum value : **255** & size of column: **30 bytes**

Choice (multiple selection) field maximum value: **350** & size of column: **22 bytes**

**My question is:**

Why I am able to add 10 options for choice column and not faced any limitation issues? Each option contains 50 characters.

And what does it mean 30 bytes? My Choice column contains 10*50 characters. 500char = 500bytes.

Is official or ShareGate information correct and up to date?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**First of all,** you should be aware of list row size limit is **8,000 bytes** per row,

- **300** bytes are reserved.
- **7700** bytes for end-user columns.

It's a **boundary limit** that can't be changed!

> For more details, check **[SharePoint 2019 Limitations compared to other SharePoint versions.](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/sharepoint-2019-limitations/)**

---

**Secondly,** this info is correct " the maximum columns for Choice (multiple selections) are **350** and its size should be **22** bytes.

**BUT**, it's the **Threshold Limit Type** that can be exceeded,

> **Note:** `350 * 22 = 7700` that is the  **Boundary Row Limit size** for end-user columns.
>
> Read more about **[Threshold vs Boundary vs Supported Limit](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/sharepoint-2013-boundariesthresholds-and-limits/)**.

**Therefore,** you will be able to add a choice field with 500 bytes without any limitation issue **UNTIL** you reach the **Boundary Row Limit size** that is 7700 bytes for end-user columns.

---

**See Also**

- **[List and Library limits in SharePoint 2016 compared to SharePoint 2013 / 2010 / 2007](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/compare-sharepoint-2016-list-library-limits-with-sharepoint-2013-2010/)**
- **[Site Collection limits in SharePoint 2016 compared to SharePoint 2013 / 2010 / 2007](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/comparing-a-site-collection-limits-in-sharepoint-2016-with-sharepoint-201320102007/)**

Comment: So the information below(from ShareGate site) is not true?
**Behind-the-scenes, a Choice column's values are stored as concatenated text. The total limit for this is 255 characters, so if you have 50 choices, each one can only be 4-characters long on average (a semicolon is used to separate each value in the concatenation).**

Comment: Regardless of what is mentioned in other articles, you will not get any limitation issue UNTIL you reach the Boundary Row Limit size that is 7700 bytes for end-user columns. as I told you in my answer it's a Threshold limit that can be exceeded!